# Merge, Union, Intersect C# List of Objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, c#-4.0, ienumerable

I am trying to solve this problem:

I have multiple array of string with some having duplicate items. I need to come up with a final list that has most items in each list

```
a1 = Array{"A", "B", "C","D","E","F"}; 
a2 = Array{"A", "B", "B", "C","D","D","D","E","F"}; 
a3 = Array{"A", "B", "B", "C","D","D","E","F"};
a4 =  Array{"A", "B", "B", "B", "C","D","D","E","F"}; 
a5 = Array{"A", "B", "B", ","D","D","E","E","F"};
```

Final result should be:

```
FinalArray = {"A", "B", "B", "B", "C","D","D","D","E","E""F"};
```

Max. occurrence each items accounted in the final result.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you even determine which items from which arrays you keep? Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @John Notice that `a5` doesn't even compile

Comment: Your code doesn't compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to solve do this is to first create a list to store the results, and then iterate through the unique items in each array, and add the difference between the count of items in the current array with the count of items in the results (if it's a positive number).

For example:

```
var arrays = new[]
{
    new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"},
    new[] {"A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "F"},
    new[] {"A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F"},
    new[] {"A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F"},
    new[] {"A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E", "F"},
};

var result = new List<string>();

foreach (var array in arrays)
{
    var distinctItems = array.Distinct();

    foreach (var distinctItem in distinctItems)
    {
        var diff = array.Count(i => i == distinctItem) - 
                   result.Count(i => i == distinctItem);

        if (diff > 0) result.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(distinctItem, diff));
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result.OrderBy(i => i)));
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework problem so I'm not sure if you're supposed to use specific methods/logic to solve it but I'll describe how I'd solve it.

Break down the problem.  The requirement (as I understand it) is to display each value the max number of times it appears in any one set.  The first step would be to count how many times each value appears in each set, which can be accomplished using ‘GroupBy’ then the ‘Count’ aggregate:

```
aN.GroupBy( v => v )
    .Select( g => new
    {
        Value = g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
    } );
```

Similarly, we would then combine the results into a single set and group them by value to obtain the ‘Max’ Count value for use in producing the result set:

```
combinedResults.GroupBy( at => at.Value )
    .Select( g => new
    {
        Value = g.Key,
        Count = g.Max( at => at.Count ),
    } );
```

Before we continue, let's combine the first two steps, but even before that, let's combine the arrays into their own set of sets.

```
var sets = new List<IEnumerable<string>>    
{
    new string[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" },
    new string[]{ "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "F" },
    ... etc ...
};

var valueMaxCounts = sets
    .Select( s =>
        s.GroupBy( v => v )
            .Select( g => new
            {
                Value = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count(),
            } ) )
    .GroupBy( at => at.Value )
    .Select( g => new
    {
        Value = g.Key,
        Count = g.Max( at => at.Count ),
    } );
```

So now we have a set of Values with the max number of times each value appeared in one of the input sets.  We now want to iterate through the results and add each value `Count` times.

```
var resultList = new List<string>();

foreach( var vmc in valueMaxCounts )
{
    //for( var i = 0; i < vmc.Count; ++I )
    //{
    //    resultList.Add( vmc.Value );
    //}

    resultList.AddRange( Enumerable.Repeat( vmc.Value, vmc.Count ) );
}
```

The final `Select` of the query and loop can be replaced with a call to `SelectMany`:

```
...query up to .GroupBy( at => at.Value )...
.SelectMany( g => Enumerable.Repeat( g.Key, g.Max( at => at.Count ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
var arrays = new[]
{
    new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"},
    new[] {"A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "F"},
    new[] {"A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F"},
    new[] {"A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E", "F"},
    new[] {"A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E", "F"},
};

var result =
    arrays
        .SelectMany(xs => xs.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() }))
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Count)
        .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Max() })
        .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x.Key, x.Count))
        .ToArray();
```

That gives: `A, B, B, B, C, D, D, D, E, E, F`

Comment: Thanks for the solution.